# my scrollview does not show the last item (Button)

Tags: java, android, xml

i am new to android and i have this xml page and when i am running the app , the last item is not showing.i have tried changing the last item to an edittext but the problem remains the same.This xml page is inflated in a fragment.Can someone help.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rel1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="com.msu.admin.subdueandroid.Calendering">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/btnbg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="SEMESTER CALENDAR"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/grestarts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedtextfield"
                android:hint="Online Registration Starts(returning)"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textColor="#002b1b" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gorstart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/grestarts"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedtextfield"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:hint="Orientation and Registration (new students)"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textColor="#002b1b" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gstart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/gorstart"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedtextfield"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:hint="Semester Starts"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textColor="#002b1b" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/semstart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/gstart"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedtextfield"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:hint="Semester Break Starts"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textColor="#002b1b" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/semend"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/semstart"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedtextfield"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:hint="Semester Break Ends"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textColor="#002b1b" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/exstart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/semend"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedtextfield"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:hint="Semester Exam Start"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textColor="#002b1b" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/exend"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/exstart"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedtextfield"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:hint="Semester Exam End"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textColor="#002b1b" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/semsend"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/exend"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedtextfield"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:hint="Semester Ends"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:textColor="#002b1b" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btncalendar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/semsend"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btnbg"
                android:text="POST CALENDAR"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why there is linearlayout?

Comment: Remove that linearlayout and change the height of ScrollView to match parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do like this May be there is no need for ScrollView

```
    <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="com.msu.admin.subdueandroid.Calendering"
            android:id="@+id/rel1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SEMESTER CALENDAR"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/btnbg"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/grestarts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:textColor="#002b1b"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedtextfield"
                android:hint="Online Registration Starts(returning)"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:inputType="none"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gorstart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:textColor="#002b1b"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedtextfield"
                android:hint="Orientation and Registration (new students)"
                android:layout_below="@+id/grestarts"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:inputType="none"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gstart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:textColor="#002b1b"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedtextfield"
                android:hint="Semester Starts"
                android:layout_below="@+id/gorstart"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:inputType="none"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/semstart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:textColor="#002b1b"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedtextfield"
                android:hint="Semester Break Starts"
                android:layout_below="@+id/gstart"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:inputType="none"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/semend"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:textColor="#002b1b"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedtextfield"
                android:hint="Semester Break Ends"
                android:layout_below="@+id/semstart"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:inputType="none"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/exstart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:textColor="#002b1b"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedtextfield"
                android:hint="Semester Exam Start"
                android:layout_below="@+id/semend"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:inputType="none"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/exend"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:textColor="#002b1b"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedtextfield"
                android:hint="Semester Exam End"
                android:layout_below="@+id/exstart"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:inputType="none"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/semsend"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.08"
                android:textColor="#002b1b"
                android:background="@drawable/roundedtextfield"
                android:hint="Semester Ends"
                android:layout_below="@+id/exend"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:cursorVisible="false"
                android:inputType="none"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btnbg"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/btncalendar"
                android:text="POST CALENDAR"
                android:layout_below="@+id/semsend" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Did you made any changes in your answer while referring to the question? I am unable to find any change. If yes, then this is not an answer!

Comment: thanx a lot i appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Add one more Relative layout in Linear Layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btnbg"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/btncalendar"
    android:text="POST CALENDAR"
   />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView can only have one child, so remove either the `Linear Layout` or `Relative Layout` in your code.
Sort all the code properly so that all of the code is `INSIDE` ScrollView, not `UNDER` it.

Comment: In the code, ScrollView is still hosting only one child. Although, there is no need for two level view hierarchy. So, either LinearLayout or RelativeLayout can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Add some padding bottom on your parent LinearLayout like:

```
android:paddingBottom="15dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button could be behind the navigation bar. To check if this is the case. Just add another button under the btncalendar, with visibility="invisible". OR just add paddingBottom="40dp" to your Relative layout. And check if the btncalendar is visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix: Add margin or padding at the bottom of the last item. It will do the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33082958)